# How to understand Laravel framework completely?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-authorization

I have gone through Laravel beginners tutorial, and now I can understand every topics listed in those tutorials and have created my own project, but as I saw in those, the tutors were able to understand what each file was meant for and had the capability to edit it and change it as per their needs.

So how do they learn so deeply and from which source?

Comment: Look at https://laracasts.com/
Ans sure at https://laravel.com/docs

Comment: They read the docs, and most importantly read the source code. The source of the Laravel framework is very easy to navigate due the use of namespaces. The easiest way to know what to use, and exactly how the codebase works is to read the source.

Comment: Source in the sense, you meant about the all the files in the laravel folder, right?

Comment: @rranj -- I mean browse the appropriate version tag on github and take a look at how some of it works. That, in combination with Laracasts and reading the laravel documentation you should have a solid foundation for working in the framework.

And by read, I don't mean read it like a book start to finish. As you develop, take a look at what methods are available on the classes you're utilizing.

Comment: Ok thank you,  I will try this

Comment: There is no shortcuts to learning. Just keep building things in it, poking around the documentation, even the source code on GitHub.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will try brief what is said at [Laravel Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure)

### **The root directory**

In the root directory of every Laravel project you can find the following directories:

- The `app` directory, as you might expect, contains the core code of your application. Models, controllers, services, middlewares are stored here.
- The `bootstrap` folder contains a few files that bootstrap the framework and configure autoloading, as well as a cache folder that contains a few framework generated files for bootstrap performance optimization. Commonly you don't need touch this folder.
- The `config` directory, as the name implies, contains all of your application's configuration files. You have to set your database connections, email drivers, sessions storage configuration (and much more), here.
- The `database` folder contains your database migration and seeds. If you wish, you may also use this folder to hold an SQLite database. Migrations allows you define your database without writing any SQL code. It's very useful if you are interested at versioning your database structure. [See more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations)
- The `public` directory contains the front controller and your assets (images, JavaScript, CSS, etc.).
- The `resources` directory contains your views, raw assets (LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript), and localization files. By default, views uses the view engine named blade, but you could change this in the `config` folder.
- The `storage` directory contains compiled Blade templates, file based sessions, file caches, and other files generated by the framework. This folder is segregated into app, framework, and logs directories. The app directory may be used to store any files utilized by your application. The framework directory is used to store framework generated files and caches. Finally, the logs directory contains your application's log files.
- The `tests` directory contains your automated tests. An example PHPUnit is provided out of the box.
- The `vendor` directory contains your Composer dependencies and the libraries needed for you application. Each library installed through composer will be stored here.

### **App folder**

The app folder contains the core code of your application. There different directories inside this folder, each one has an specific purpose:

- The `app` directory ships with a variety of additional directories such as Console, Http, and Providers. Think of the Console and Http directories as providing an API into the "core" of your application. The HTTP protocol and CLI are both mechanisms to interact with your application, but do not actually contain application logic. In other words, they are simply two ways of issuing commands to your application. The Console directory contains all of your [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/master/artisan) commands, while the Http directory contains your [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers), [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware), and [requests](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests). The [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing) of your application are defined in this directory also.
- The `Events` directory, as you might expect, houses event classes. Events may be used to alert other parts of your application that a given action has occurred, providing a great deal of flexibility and decoupling. [Check this link for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events)
- The `Exceptions` directory contains your application's exception handler and is also a good place to stick any exceptions thrown by your application.
- The `Jobs` directory, of course, houses the queueable jobs for your application. Jobs may be queued by your application or run synchronously within the current request lifecycle. [There is more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues).
- The `Listeners` directory contains the handler classes for your events. Handlers receive an event and perform logic in response to the event being fired. For example, a UserRegistered event might be handled by a SendWelcomeEmail listener.
- The `Policies` directory contains the authorization policy classes for your application. Policies are used to determine if a user can perform a given action against a resource. [More info here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization).